# How to retrieve the results of AjaxSpider scan using the Java APIs of ZAP

Tags: java, security, owasp, zap, penetration-testing

When I executed the [Spider](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#using-spider) scan using the Java API of ZAP I got expected results as follows:

- Code:

  ```
  System.out.println("Spider completed");
  List<ApiResponse> spiderResults = ((ApiResponseList)api.spider.results(scanID)).getItems(); 
  // printing Spider results  
  for (ApiResponse spiderResult:spiderResults) 
      System.out.println(spiderResult);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Spider completed
  https://public-firing-range.appspot.com/sitemap.xml
  https://public-firing-range.appspot.com/robots.txt
  https://public-firing-range.appspot.com
  ```

But when I execute the [AjaxSpider](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#using-ajax-spider) scan using the Java API of ZAP I don't get the results as expected as obtained from Spider scan output.

- Code:

  ```
  System.out.println("Ajax Spider completed");
  List<ApiResponse> ajaxSpiderResponse = ((ApiResponseList) api.ajaxSpider.results("0", "10")).getItems();
  // printing Spider results  
  for (ApiResponse ajaxSpiderResp:ajaxSpiderResponse) 
      System.out.println(ajaxSpiderResp);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Ajax Spider completed
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@5ce65a89
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@25f38edc
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@1a86f2f1
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@3eb07fd3
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@506c589e
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@69d0a921
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@446cdf90
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@799f7e29
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@4b85612c
  org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseSet@277050dc
  ```

How can I retrieve the results of AjaxSpider scan using the Java API of ZAP in human readable format. I am not sure what I am missing here. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

ApiResponseSet is a Java class: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-java/blob/develop/subprojects/zap-clientapi/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/clientapi/core/ApiResponseSet.java

You can use the toString(0) method to get a human readable format and the other methods to extract any of the contents.